# How to break span elements using css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, line-breaks

I am having a container `div` with selected items and select input inside it.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

._2iA8p44d0WZ {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 22px;
    position: relative;
}

._7ahQImy {
  padding: 4px 10px;
    background: #0096fb;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="_2iA8p44d0WZ">
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy">This is the main label</span>
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy false false">secondary label</span>
  <input type="text" class="searchBox" id="search_input" placeholder="Select" autocomplete="off" value="">
</div>
</div>
```

**Requirement:**

-> I am in the need to move the selected items below the `#container` div to display individual chips (span tags) below one after the other.

**Note:**
-> There are some dynamic classes inside it for which I cannot modify the css classes for those dynamic classes.

List of dynamic classes for which css properties cannot be modified, `_2iA8p44d0WZ` and `_7ahQImy` .

List of ids/classes,  I can modify the css properties are `#container` and `.chip` (span).

**Things I have tried:**

Added css property for span element with class `chip` as follows,

```
.chip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
}


.chip:after {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

But this results in the overlapping of items one on another.

If I add `display: block;` to `.chip` then that also results the same..

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

._2iA8p44d0WZ {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 22px;
    position: relative;
}

._7ahQImy {
  padding: 4px 10px;
    background: #0096fb;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.chip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200%;
}


.chip:after {
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="_2iA8p44d0WZ">
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy">This is the main label</span>
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy false false">secondary label</span>
  <input type="text" class="searchBox" id="search_input" placeholder="Select" autocomplete="off" value="">
</div>
</div>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
---------------------------
| Input                   |
---------------------------

| This is the main label |

| secondary label    |
```

Kindly please help me to modify the css of span tags `(.chip)` **without modifying the dynamic classes** (I don't have control for it in real application) to have line breaks, so that it will be visible one after the other below the container.

Comment: you could've used `<br>` after `<span>`, or `display: block` property in `.chip` class. Don't need to do position absolute otherwise it'll overlap each other.

Comment: The problem is that you are positioning them absolute, of course they will end up on top of each other, if you position them all with the same `top` value. Doing this the other way around would IMHO make much more sense here - position the input field absolute at the top of the container, and leave those chips in normal flow instead. Add a padding-top for the container element, so that they don’t go beneath the input field, but under it.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for your comment.. Can you post a solution based on your inputs for better understanding please?

Comment: @spyshiv, That didn't work the way expected.. Its still the same result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are positioning the chips absolute, of course they will end up on top of each other, if you position them all with the same top value.

Doing this the other way around would IMHO make much more sense here - position the input field absolute at the top of the container, and leave those chips in normal flow instead. Add a padding-top for the inner container element, so that they don’t go beneath the input field, but under it.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width:100%;
}

#container > div {
    padding-top: 2em;
}

._2iA8p44d0WZ {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 22px;
    position: relative;
}

._7ahQImy {
  padding: 4px 10px;
    background: #0096fb;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#search_input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="_2iA8p44d0WZ">
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy">This is the main label</span>
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy false false">secondary label</span>
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy">Another label</span>
  <span class="chip _7ahQImy false false">even more labels labels labels labels labels labels</span>
  <input type="text" class="searchBox" id="search_input" placeholder="Select" autocomplete="off" value="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Again sorry in no way I cannot modify the dynamic class css properties which I also mentioned in question.. Reason: Those dynamic class names will change dynamically always we render a page.. So really we don't have a control over those dynamic classes..

Comment: So that would apply only to the adding of the padding-top to the inner container here then? Then select that based on that it is a first-level child of the outer container then, `#container > div { padding-bottom: 2em; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use in html br tag, in Css you can try

```css
.container{
width: 100px;/*insert the px you need, make som tests*/
}
.your-stuff{
display:flex;
flex-warp: warp;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container"> 
     <div class="my-stuff">stuff</div>
  </div>
</body>
```